# No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal. This is a common source of bugs when children are added dynamically

Tags: android, xml

My application can not be run since there is an error in my xml-file. One of my LinearLayouts are marked red and by hovering I can see the following error message: 
No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal. This is a common source of bugs when children are added dynamically.

You can see my code below and I will mark the line were I get this message as follows: 
<- error message ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment 1"
            />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment 2"
            />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fragment 3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout             <- error message -> 
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I forgot to mark where in the code that I got that error message but it is now done. I want to make my code runnable. So LinearLayout is red at the marked line where the error message was: No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal. This is a common source of bugs when children are added dynamically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add `android:orientation="horizontal"` in the `LinearLayout` block, same thing as you did above.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse ADT, I've sometimes noticed that the error won't go away immediately if you just add `android:orientation="vertical"`. Lint needs to be re-run, and so usually a Project->Clean will help in this case if you've added the attribute for orientation and the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout needs an orientation, horizontal or vertical.

You can set it in code :

```
myLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Where should I write that?

Answer (score 0):

See below you need to add an orientation for the layout.

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:orientation="horizontal"          
    android:id="@+id/myFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" />
```